# Is there a function in PHP that uses Regex and returns an array of results?

Tags: php, regex, list

`preg_match` returns only the first result.
lets say I have the string `abcabcabc` and I wanna find ALL indexes of ABC. (ofcourse mine is a bit more complex...) - how can I do it ?
Thank you!

Comment: `preg_match` does not even return the result, it returns the number of matches. However, it **populates** an array passed by reference as the 3rd argument. So does `preg_match_all`, but with all results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**preg_match_all**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

You simply have to pass in a variable as the third argument that will be loaded up with all your matches.

[Example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php#101259)

```
<?php
$pattern = "/{[^}]*}/";
$subject = "{token1} foo {token2} bar";
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {token1}
            [1] => {token2}
        )

)
```

Comment: preg_match_all is needed. preg_match will populate the third argument with a single match.

Answer (score 2):

preg_match_all does not suite you? [preg_match_all](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_match_all( $pattern, $subject, $matches )
```

Used like this preg_match_all returns an int but populates the $matches array.
[Look here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) for function documentation.
Your example can be solved like this:

```
$subject = "abcabcabc";
$pattern = "/abc/";
if( preg_match_all( $pattern, $subject, $matches ) ) {
    print_r($matches);
} else {
    echo "No match.";
}
```